# Unwrapping Enveloped CMS data with key from AndroidKeyStore in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cryptography, android-keystore

I need to unwrap/decrypt a cms file that has Enveloped data.

I can do something like the following and it works well

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import("/sdcard/decryption-key.p12", <password>, X509KeyStorageFlags.DefaultKeySet);

X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(cert);

EnvelopedCms cms = new EnvelopedCms();

cms.Decode(<content info>);
cms.Decrypt(certCollection);
```

This creates a X509Certificate2 from a p12 file on the file system.
However I want to have that key/Cert stored securely in the AndroidKeyStore.

I have found some code that allows me to load the p12 into the keystore ([Import .p12-file into AndroidKeyStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713011/import-p12-file-into-androidkeystore))

How do I load the data out of the key store to create the `X509Certificate2` as above, Or how do I call `cms.Decrypt` with a key from the key store?

Thanks

Comment: you could refer to this:https://github.com/kagkarlsson/cms-decrypt-example/blob/master/src/main/java/no/posten/dpost/EncryptAndDecrypt.java, written with Java.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Thanks but that example gets the X509Certificate data from a file, like my example above. I am trying to load keys from the AndroidKeyStore and have the keys remain within the secure execution environment (TEE) so the keys are not exposed. Is this possible with the CMS API?
I would also like to avoid having to use a thirdparty library (Bouncy Castle) if possible